# Renaming image files

Tags: c#, image, rename

I would like to rename a directory (`C:\Users\userPC\Desktop\MATT\PROVA\IMG\AW12`) that contains 3.000 image files with `C#`. These images actually have this type of name:

```
area1_area2_area3_area4.jpg
```

I would like to take the area2 and area4 to form a new file renamed to `area2_area4.jpg`. These areas haven't a regular number of character. How can I do? I've found this discussion [Rename image files on server directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603795/rename-image-files-on-server-directory)

But I'm a newbie with programming and I can't work our how to solve my problem.

Comment: That would be really simple using the classes in `System.IO` and `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. Ask google for some help on those namespaces and this won't take you long!

Comment: do you have some area separator between areas? I mean for example '_'

Comment: @looper I've tried some code taked from the web but doesn't work. My idea was to use the FileStream but I'm still newbie to write a complete script by myself, unfortunately.

Comment: @trippino yes, the underline separates the four areas.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.Please be aware that it will not check before making any mess :)

```
public void rename(String path)
{
  string[] files =System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
  foreach(string s in files)
  {
     string[] ab=s.split('_');
     if(ab.Lenght>3)  
     {
         string newName=ab[1]+ab[3];
         System.IO.File.Move(s,path+newName);
     }
  }
}
```

You must call the method using this type of parameter

```
rename("C://Users//userPC//Desktop//MATT//PROVA//IMG//AW12//")
```

The separator can be changed here ->`s.split('_')`

Comment: Thanks nucandrei for your time. I've try your code but I've obtain an error message by debugger JIt that say "index beyond the bounds of the array. Continue. Quit". You know why?

Comment: Probably inside the folder there are some files that don't have 3 separators. You should check it before setting the newName. Try to add "if(ab.Lenght>3){string newName=...."

Comment: trippino might have a good hint.This error is usually when accesing indices not supported by your array.So, in this case you have some files that don't respect area1_area2_area3_area4.jpg format

Comment: Thanks for the hint. In fact I see that there are some articles with only 3 areas. I've deleted them  and, however, I've added the control you've suggested to me. But unfortunately still generates an exception: "unable to create a file if already exists"
?!?!
And about the parameters in the last line: isn't correct to write "System.IO.File.Move(newName, path);"?

Comment: This message is appearing now because the renaming operation succedded on several files (before getting the error)

Comment: Thanks! :) And if I want to save these images file to another directory? **System.IO.File.Create(path + "//NEW//");** It's right? Because in this way I've obtaining another exception: "unable to find a part of the path". Or maybe: **System.IO.File.Copy(newName, path);** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Rename all files in the C:\Temp\ directory.
            Program.RenameFiles(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp\"));
        }

        public static void RenameFiles(DirectoryInfo path)
        {
            // Does the path exist?
            if (path.Exists)
            {
                // Get all files in the directory.
                FileInfo[] files = path.GetFiles("*.jpg");
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    // Split the filename
                    string[] parts = file.Name.Split('_');
                    // Concatinate the second and fourth part.
                    string newFilename = string.Concat(parts[1], "_", parts[3]);
                    // Combine the original path with the new filename.
                    string newPath = Path.Combine(path.FullName, newFilename);
                    // Move the file.
                    File.Move(file.FullName, newPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrik for your time. I've try your code but I've obtain this error: "unhandled exception: cannot create a file" ( http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/343/csharp.png )

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of file names contained in the folder with

```
var listOfFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
```

You mentioned that the areas do not have a regular number of characters (I assume that the areas are separated by the underscore character). So split each file name into it's four areas, using the underscore character as a separator.

Then build your new file name, for exmple,

```
foreach(var fileName in listOfFileNames)
{
    var areas = fileName.Split('_');
    var newFileName = string.Format({0}{1}{2}, areas[0], areas[1],".jpg");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks user65439 for your time. I've try this:

<code>void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var listOfFileNames = Directory.GetFiles("C://Users//userPC//Desktop//MATT SUPERDRY//PROVA//IMG//AW12//");
   foreach(var fileName in listOfFileNames)
   {
       var areas = fileName.Split('_');
       var newFileName = string.Format({0}{1}{2}, areas[1], areas[3], ".jpg");
       File.Move(fileName, listOfFileNames + newFileName);
}</code>

but it generate some errors in the line of "var newFileName". :(